# How to prevent an app opened repeat

Tags: android

I use the following code to add an icon to  Notification status, a user can click the icon to open the app ui.SMSMain.class, and the two ui.SMSMain.class apps will be opened if the user click the icon two times.
I hope the app only can be opened one time, how can I do?

```
private static void ShowNotification() {        
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) myContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.smsforward,
                                    myContext.getString(R.string.app_name), 
                                    System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; 
    CharSequence contentTitle =myContext.getString(R.string.NotificationTitle); 
    CharSequence contentText = myContext.getString(R.string.NotificationContent); 

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(myContext, ui.SMSMain.class); 
    PendingIntent contentItent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(myContext, contentTitle, contentText,contentItent);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationID, notification);
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the target activity's launch mide single_top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `launchMode` attribute to your activity in the manifest as SingleTop

```
<activity
        android:name="Tracking"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        ....
```

this will allow only one instance of the activity, also it is better to use flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in your pendingIntent

```
PendingIntent contentItent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

though, I am not sure if 0 actual refer to UPDATE_CURRENT

**Update**

you may need to choose among singleTop or singleTask according to your needs

for singleTop: if an instance of activity already exists at the top of the current task and system routes intent to this activity, no new instance will be created

for singleTask: A new task will always be created and a new instance will be pushed to the task as the root one. However, if any activity instance exists in any tasks, the system routes the intent to that activity instance through the onNewIntent() method call.

for more [information](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) about LaunchMode.

I believe that singleTop suits your problem better.

Comment: It sounds more like the main class to a bunch of tasks by his descriptions, so I would maybe even consider singleTask

Comment: thanks for sharing, however I think from what I understood that he want to redirect to the opened activity without launching a new one, so I considered singleTop.